# How to extract a number from a two line string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to extract the number "40" from following two lines:

```
Total Boys:4 (40 min)
Main Students:0 (0 min)
```

How can I do that using javascript? Thank in advance!

Comment: "*How can I do that using javascript?*" Use a regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a regular expression:

```
var str = 'Total Boys:4 (40 min)\nMain Students: 0 (0 min)';
var number = str.match(/\((\d+)/)[1]; // 40
```

Answer (score 1):

Or without a regex

```
str.split('min').shift().split('(').pop().trim();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/u6ee8/1/)

Comment: This answer is super awesome.

Comment: @OmarTariq - It has rhythm, so you can even sing it ;.) ....

Comment: I used very similar algorithm to write the answer. First, it took me so long, and secondly, it was on approx. 10 lines. And when I saw this answer then I felt embarrassed and closed my jsfiddle. It feels bad to be a js noob. However, I learned few new things from your answer. `:)`

Comment: This answer works for me. Now I would like to extract '90' from the example below: var str = 'Total Boys:4 (40 min)\nMain Students: 0 (90 min)';
var msg = str.split('(').pop().trim(); 
alert(msg); //answer I got is  "90 min)", can you please advice me?

Comment: I solved above problem by using "str.split('(').pop().trim().split('min').shift();"

Comment: @user3216113 - If you didn't use a regex, why did you accept an answer that uses a regex ?

Comment: @adeneo -first I used regex, it worked for me. Then I use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple regex to pull that value out:

```
var str = 'Total Boys:4 (40 min)\nMain Students:0 (0 min)';
var regexp = /.*\((\d+) min\)\n.*/;
var matches = regexp.exec(str);
alert('match: ' + matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it would be simply `str.match(/\d+/g)[1]` using **regex.**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/swyGb/)**

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have your string inside **str** andyou want to store the number inside **n**

another approach is this:

```
var index1,
    index2,
    index3,
    n;

index1 = str.indexOf('Total Boys:', 0);
index2 = str.indexOf('(', index1) + 1;
index3 = str.indexOf(' ', index2);

n = str.substring(index2, index3);
```

note that this approach will get only the **min** value of "Total Boys", not "Main Students".
It will work even if you have another similar line before "Total Boys"